Get the mean of total count grouped by multiple columns in Pandas
I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks like this:



type
location
pass
enrolled




student
US
yes
highschool


student
CA
yes
highschool


teacher
US
yes
college


teacher
US
no
college


student
US
no
highschool


student
CA
yes
college


student
CA
no
college



I want to get the pass rate and group it by type, location, and enrolled so it looks something like this:



type
location
enrolled
pass_rate




student
US
highschool
.5


student
CA
highschool
1.0


student
CA
college
.5


teacher
US
college
1.0



To create the above dataframe:
import pandas as pd

list_of_dict = [
    {"type": "student", "location": "US", "pass": "yes", "enrolled": "highschool"},
    {"type": "student", "location": "CA", "pass": "yes", "enrolled": "highschool"},
    {"type": "teacher", "location": "US", "pass": "yes", "enrolled": "college"},
    {"type": "teacher", "location": "US", "pass": "no", "enrolled": "college"},
    {"type": "student", "location": "US", "pass": "no", "enrolled": "highschool"},
    {"type": "student", "location": "CA", "pass": "yes", "enrolled": "college"},
    {"type": "student", "location": "CA", "pass": "no", "enrolled": "college"},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)

I know I need to get the .count() while grouping by "type", "location", and "enrolled".
I've tried:
df = df.groupby(["type", "location", "enrolled"]).count().mean()

But this just gives me an integer.

Code
use crosstab with normalize=0
out = (pd.crosstab([df['type'], df['location'], df['enrolled']], 
                    df['pass'], normalize=0)['yes']
         .reset_index(name='pass_rate')
)

out:
      type location    enrolled  pass_rate
0  student       CA     college        0.5
1  student       CA  highschool        1.0
2  student       US  highschool        0.5
3  teacher       US     college        0.5


if you want use groupby, then use following code:
out = (
    df['pass'].eq('yes')
    .groupby([df['type'], df['location'], df['enrolled']])
    .mean()
    .reset_index(name='pass_rate')
)

same result

You can replace 'yes' and 'no' with 1 and 0 respectively on column 'pass', then groupby on the other columns and get the mean.
df["pass"] = df["pass"].map({"yes": 1, "no": 0})

df = (
    df.groupby(["type", "location", "enrolled"])["pass"]
    .mean()
    .reset_index(name="pass_rate")
)

      type location    enrolled  pass_rate
0  student       CA     college        0.5
1  student       CA  highschool        1.0
2  student       US  highschool        0.5
3  teacher       US     college        0.5


Plus 1 from me....  great solution using mean.

You can also perform in-place replacement
df.replace({'pass': {'yes':1, 'no':0}}).groupby.....
